# Bott projection

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

This is part of an exercise problem (5.I) in Wegge-Olsen's book "K-theory and $C^*$-algebras".

There he defines the Bott projection for $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $B:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{M}_2$, $B(z)=B(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+|z|^2}\begin{pmatrix} |z|^2 & z \\ \bar{z} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $z=x+iy$. Then he writes that the Bott projection is constant in infinity in the sense that $B(z)\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$; and that $B(0)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Thus the Bott projection may be considered a function in the unitization of $S^{2} \mathbb{M}_{2}$, where $S^2$ denotes double suspension.

It looks like the statements about $B(\infty)$ and $B(0)$ are wrong (if someone can confirm this). I also don't quite understand the last statement. Hope that someone can explain it to me.

Next, he defines a map $u_0:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{M}_2$ by $u_0(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2+|y|^2}}\begin{pmatrix} x+iy & -1 \\ 1 & x-iy \end{pmatrix}$, and asks to prove that $u_0$ is unitary, and that $B=u_0\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}u_0^*$.

Can someone please help me with the part about it being unitary?

Comment: Clearly, $B(\infty)$ and $B(0)$ have been swapped. Misprints happen.

Comment: As for $u_0$ being unitary, its columns are orthogonal unit vectors. If you don't get that, you probably forgot to take complex conjugates of one of the vectors in taking the inner product.

Comment: Thanks. Now all that's left is for me to understand that statement about the double suspension.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help with that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of $B(\infty)$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix, the function $B$ does not seem to belong to the unitization of $S^2\mathbb M_2$ as claimed, but rather to $\mathbb M_2$ of the unitization of $S^2\mathbb C$.